# Angular2 i18n strings parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I can't find the proper way to translate a string with parameters using the default Angular i18n module.

```
<h1 i18n>Hello %user%!</h1>
```

I could write it like

```
<h1 i18n>Hello {{user.name}}!</h1>
```

But then, the translator would have to deal with angular syntax, and it can get worse if the parameter uses pipes. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, the translator won't have to deal with angular syntax. Just test it.

Comment: What about translating `<h1 i18n>Your balance {{user.balance | currency:'USD':true:'4.2-2'}}!</h1>`?

Comment: Again, doesn't change anything. Just test it. All the translator sees is `Your balance is <x id="INTERPOLATION"/>!`

Comment: Thank you! Although that doesn't works for me, as I'm migrating an AngularJS project that uses placeholders like %name%  I'll figure out something else